# Auto-update Excel cell size in response to dynamic content

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Context:** I have a sheet with a drop-down with different categories. The sheet also has a table whose information updates depending on what category is selected from the drop-down. Some of the categories yield lots of text, requiring large cells, and some have only small amounts of text, requiring small cells.

**What I’m seeking:** What I am looking for is a way that cell size will auto-update depending on how much text is in the cell for any given category. *I understand how to do this* *manually,* by highlighting the whole page and clicking auto-fit or double clicking the column or row dividers. However, I would like a way for this to happen as soon as I select a drop-down item. The reason is that different people will be using this sheet, and if they don’t know they need to manually update cell sizes, they may miss critical information because the sheet is set to small cell sizes and it isn’t obvious that text has been cut off. Conversely, if I set the table to very large cell sizes by default, then when a category is selected that only yields small amounts of text, the table is way larger and more unwieldy than it needs to be.

Does anyone know of a way for cell sizes to auto-updates as soon as the amount of text in them changes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make a macro to update the column width whenever a cell in that column is changed.

Cells change because of user input or because of formula re-calculation.  You would use a different type of macro of each type of change.  The following is a typical example for manual inputs in column **C**:

Insert the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cells(1, "C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you, Gary's student! This worked for adjusting column size. Now I'm wondering if I can do the same for row height. I tried adjusting your formula but did not quite get it. I imagine it must be something like this:

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("4:4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cells(4, "b").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub